# Objective c ios- Backgrounds of UITableViewCell all messed up

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a problem in tableview, I am setting background of uitableviewcell but when i scroll tableview the background image overlaps the cell's image and text. I dont know the reason. here is the code. kindly help me. Thanks.

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Workout strip.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.opaque = NO;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
cell.backgroundView.tag = indexPath.row;
[imageView release];
cell.textLabel.text = [exerciseNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Workout video box.png"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off get rid of this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
```

None of your cells will ever be reused, this is BAD! And most likely a big part of your problem

instead do this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

Don't set the background view to clear, it's not good for performance. You want subviews to be Opaque unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: actually, his cells will be reused if he has multiple sections :)

Comment: removing opaque and background view from clear solved my problem :) Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I will never understand the background color of a `UITableViewCell` can only be set from within this call in your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do whatever you need to do to your cell here to make it look the way you want
}
```

Detailed discussion is in the documentation for [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW8).

Comment: That's quite strange, because I do remember setting the backgroundView for cells within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and it worked fine in my app...